# Conocedores de java ¿Es esto lo mas optimo?

Tags: java

Tengo entendedido que siempre hay una forma mas optima pero estoy haciendo  una especie de tamagochi básico con mis pocos conocimientos. Funciona, pero. a medida que voy avanzando me pregunto, ¿estoy haciendo uso correcto de los métodos?, ya que lo que hago es inicializar un montón de métodos dentro de una sola clase y al arrancar el programa estos se reinician constantemente con un timer y un timertask de 1 segundo, ciento que me ha quedado muy largo el código y mal gasto recursos Como podría simplificarlo o mejorarlo :)

nota: ¿vale para pasarlo a swing? //no se nada de swing, aun//

````
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
/**
* tama
*/
public class pollant {

  //STATS Normales
  static int vitalidad=100;
  static int hambre=100;
  static int energia=100;
  static int locura=0;
  static int zona=0;
  static String nombre="";
  


 //Stats en estado de locura
 static String Ser="";
 static int diversion=100;
 static int devocion=100;
 static String filing="";
 static int zone=0;
 static int fraserandom=0;




  //COMIDAS
  static int mango = 3;  // sumara 30 
  static int banano = 5; // sumara 20
  static int manzana = 10; // sumara 10
  static int valorali = 0;


  //JUEGO






      public static void main(String[] args) {
     

      Scanner teclado1 = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Como se llamara su tamago");
      nombre= teclado1.nextLine();
      
      vitalidant();
      hambrent();
      energiantmas();
      energiantmenos();
      locurant();
      lobby();
      





  }


  public static  void lobby(){


// estado normal


System.out.println("\n"+ "\n"+"               "+nombre + "\n" +"vida:" + vitalidad + "\n" + "hambre:" + hambre + "\n" + "energia:" + energia + "\n" + "locura:" +locura);
System.out.println("\n alimentar(1)-------jugar(2)-------Inventario(3)-------actualizar(4)");

Scanner teclado3 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("");
zona = teclado3.nextInt();

if (zona==1) { alimentar();}
if (zona==2) { jugar();}



if (zona==4) {lobby();}


  }
  ///sistema de hambre
  public static void hambrent() {
      
      Timer hambrent;
      hambrent = new Timer();
      
  
      TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
          int tic=0;
  
          @Override
          public void run()
          {
              if (tic%2==0 && hambre != 0)
              {hambre --;}
          }
          };
         
      hambrent.schedule(task, 10, 100);
      }
         
      ///sistema de energia
      public static void energiantmenos(){
          
              Timer energiantmenos;
              energiantmenos = new Timer();
              TimerTask energianttask = new TimerTask() {
                  int tic=0;
          
                  @Override
                  public void run()
                  {
                      if (tic%2==0 && hambre < 50)
                      {energia --;}

                      if (tic%2==0 && vitalidad < 50)
                      {energia --;}
                      
                  }
                  
              };
              energiantmenos.schedule(energianttask, 10, 10000);
          }

              
              
              public static void energiantmas() {
                  
              
                   Timer energiantmas;
                  energiantmas = new Timer();
                  TimerTask energianttask = new TimerTask() {
                      int tic=0;
              
                      @Override
                      public void run()
                      {
                          if (tic%2==0 && vitalidad > 50 && energia != 100 )
                          {energia ++;}
                      }
                      };
                     
                  energiantmas.schedule(energianttask, 10, 10000);}
              

                  
      
      //// vitalidad y locura
      public static void locurant()
      {   ///vitality shets
         
              Timer locurant;
              locurant = new Timer();
              TimerTask locuratask = new TimerTask() {
                  int tic=0;
          
                  @Override
                  public void run()
                  {
                      if (tic%2==0 && vitalidad <= 50)
                      {locura ++;}

                      if (tic%2==0 && hambre <= 30)
                      {locura ++;}

                      if (tic%2==0 && energia <= 20)
                      {locura ++;}

                      if (tic%2==0 && locura >= 100)
                      {ESTADODELOCURA();}


                  }
                  };
                  
              locurant.schedule(locuratask, 10, 30000);}


              private static void vitalidant() {

                  Timer vitalidant;
                  vitalidant = new Timer();
                  TimerTask vitaltask = new TimerTask() {
                      int tic=0;
              
                      @Override
                      public void run()
                      {
                          if (tic%2==0 && hambre <= 0)
                          {vitalidad --;}

                          if (vitalidad <= 0){gameover();}
                      }
                      };
                      
                  vitalidant.schedule(vitaltask, 10, 10000);
                  
              }
          
               




      





  public static  void nomangos(){
      String enter;
      System.out.println("No te quedan mangos presiona enter para salir");
      Scanner tecladoman = new Scanner(System.in);
      enter = tecladoman.nextLine();
      lobby();}
      public static  void nobanano(){
          String enter;
          System.out.println("No te quedan bananos presiona enter para salir");
          Scanner tecladobano = new Scanner(System.in);
          enter = tecladobano.nextLine();
          lobby();}
          public static  void nomanzanas(){
              String enter;
              System.out.println("No te quedan manzanas presiona enter para salir");
              Scanner tecladomanzana = new Scanner(System.in);
              enter = tecladomanzana.nextLine();
              lobby();}



/**
* alimentar
*/
public static  void alimentar() {

System.out.println(" (1) dar mango"+ "("+mango+")");
System.out.println(" (2) dar banana"+ "("+banano+")");
System.out.println(" (3) dar manzana"+ "("+manzana+")");

Scanner teclado2 = new Scanner(System.in);
valorali = teclado2.nextInt();

  if (valorali == 1) {mango--;}
  if (valorali == 1 && mango > 0) {hambre += 30;}
  if (valorali == 1 && mango ==0 ) {nomangos();}
  if (valorali == 1 && mango < 0 ) {mango=0;}
 
  if (valorali == 2) {banano--;}
  if (valorali == 2 && banano > 0) {hambre += 20;}
  if (valorali == 2 && banano ==0 ) {nobanano();}
  if (valorali == 2 && banano < 0 ) {banano=0;}

  if (valorali == 3) {manzana--;}
  if (valorali == 3 && manzana > 0) {hambre += 10;}
  if (valorali == 3 && manzana ==0 ) {nomanzanas();}
  if (valorali == 3 && manzana < 0 ) {manzana=0;}
lobby();
}


public static  void jugar(){









}


public static void gameover(){

System.out.println("Your tamago Die");
System.exit(0);

}

public static void ESTADODELOCURA()
{
  System.out.println("\n"+ "\n"+"               "+nombre + "\n" +"Ser:" + Ser + "\n" + "Diversion:" + diversion + "\n" + "Devocion:" + devocion + "\n" + "Te sientes, "+ filing );
  System.out.println("\n Consumir(1)-------Masacrar(2)-------Arrepentirse(3)-------Pactar(4)-------Actualizar(5)");
 
 Scanner teclado3 = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("");
 zona = teclado3.nextInt();
 
 if (zona==1) { alimentar();}
 if (zona==2) { jugar();}
 
 
 if (zona==4) {ESTADODELOCURA();}

}

} ```
````

Comment: Ten en cuenta que las preguntas basadas en opiniones/debates terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). Lee [ask].

Comment: Hola @luisfer, padaleiana, no es "correcto" pedir opiniones, podrías editar tu pregunta para que quede algo como, **como puedo re-factorizar el siguiente código?**.

Comment: Por otro lado... por favor, identa correctamente, tu código es bastante difícil de seguir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que tienes tres timer que funcionan con los mismos tiempos, yo los juntaría:

```
private static void vidant() {
  Timer xx = new Timer();
  TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
     int tic = 0;
     @Override
    public void run() {
        if( tic % 2 == 0 && hambre < 50 ) {
            energia--;
        }
        if( tic % 2 == 0 && vitalidad < 50 ) {
            energia--;
        }
        if( tic % 2 == 0 && vitalidad <= 50 ) {
            locura++;
        }
        if( tic % 2 == 0 && hambre <= 30 ) {
            locura++;
        }
        if( tic % 2 == 0 && energia <= 20 ) {
            locura++;
        }
        if( tic % 2 == 0 && locura >= 100 ) {
            ESTADODELOCURA();
        }
        if( tic % 2 == 0 && hambre <= 0 ) {
            vitalidad--;
        }
        if( vitalidad <= 0 ) {
            gameover();
        } 
     }
  };
  xx.schedule( task, 10, 10000 );
}
```

Esto obviamente, te obliga a modificar las llamadas a los métodos:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {      //JUEGO
  Scanner teclado1 = new Scanner( System.in );
  System.out.println( "Como se llamara su tamago" );
  nombre = teclado1.nextLine();
  //vitalidant();
  vidant(); // ex vitalidant(),  ex energiantmenos(), ex energiantmas()
  hambrent();
  //energiantmas();
  //energiantmenos();
  locurant();
  lobby();
}
```

Si quieres mayor claridad en el método **vidant**, puedes crear métodos auxiliares y llamarlos desde ahí:

```
public void run() {
    vitalidant( tic );
    energiantmas( tic );
    energiantmenos( tic );
}
```

y el método en cuestión:

```
vitalidant( int tic ) {
    if( tic % 2 == 0 && hambre <= 0 ) {
       vitalidad--;
    }
    if( vitalidad <= 0 ) {
       gameover();
    }
}

void energiantmas( int tic ) {
    if( tic % 2 == 0 && vitalidad > 50 && energia != 100 ) {
        energia++;
    }
}

void energiantmenos( int tic ) {
    if( tic % 2 == 0 && hambre < 50 ) {
        energia--;
    }
    if( tic % 2 == 0 && vitalidad < 50 ) {
        energia--;
    }
}
```

Nota1: la variable **tic**, no tiene razón de ser, no la quité, pensando que tal vez, la colocaste para darle algún uso posterior, si no es así...

Nota2: no llego a tener una comprensión cabal del funcionamiento, existe la posibilidad de que el orden en que ejecutas las funciones desde el **main**, haga que la aplicación falle, en ese caso mi propuesta es inválida.

Nota3: dentro de los métodos **noxx**, creas una variable enter que no se usa, puedes quitarla.

Comment: Evita responder preguntas mal formuladas. Las mismas terminan cerradas y tu respuesta se pierde.

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras, me encanta ir contra la corriente, intento responder antes de que la cierren, así le doy una posibilidad al OP, de recibir respuesta, otros en cambio, están totalmente entregados a hacer respetar las reglas... que desconocen!!!, gracias por tu buen consejo.